# Converting VFP WRITETEXT/READTEXT to byte[]?

Tags: c#

I have run into an interesting situation.  Working on an old Visual Fox Pro 9 application written 20 years ago that uses SQL Server 2008 (and versions above depending on the client).
Back then, they opted to save the contents of a Microsoft Word document (bytes not a text extraction) to a text column in SQL Server.  In Fox Pro, the application reads the
bytes with READTEXT and writes with WRITETEXT.   These documents are referenced in a variety of places in the application this way.  So for now, it really isn't
feasible for me to correct this problem by adding a varbinary(max) column and just fix the data without introducing a considerable amount of risk when changing
a large number of places in the Fox Pro app.  The deadline I'm on just eliminates this as an option.

Where it becomes a real issue is that we have introducted .NET supporting applications that interact with the same database as part of our move away from
Fox Pro.  I'm having problems converting the huge string that comes back in the DataTable for this column into a byte[].  And, of course, would have problems saving the
document back via .NET in the same format so I don't break the Fox Pro application.

I'm guessing this has to do with encoding but the basic things I've tried such as base64 encoding this into a byte[] but is doesn't work.  Here is
a small snippet of the string that starts every document:

"7B5C727466315C616465666C616E67313032355C616E73695C"

The rest of the huge string is this same alphanumeric value set.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to handing the conversion into a byte[] and
then back out to this mess?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Hexadecimal: `7B 5C 72 74 66` etc, and when converted back into text I get this: `{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\`. So it looks like it writes & reads RTF documents using hex bytes.

You can try this code for the conversion from hex-text back to the original bytes:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var hex = "7B5C727466315C616465666C616E67313032355C616E73695C";
    var rtfBytes = FromHex(hex);
    var rtfText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rtfBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(rtfText);
}

public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
{
    var result = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return result;
}
```

See the [DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALxT8S)